# SVG2 stacking system using z-index style property seems to not be correctly interpreted

Tags: css, svg

*This topic has been asked in december 2016. Please be aware this could be not relevant if you watch this topic later.*

I was struggling with reordering my SVG using Javascript and CSS `z-index` property. I was using SVG1. I checked and every examples following are executed on Chrome latest version, and Chrome supports SVG2.

**TEST CASE**

You can check [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/834bse3t/) and play around with it around to see that the SVG 2 z-index support is not correctly working (W3C example available here : https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/render.html#ZIndexProperty, scroll a little until you see a snippet code).

In this example, I built 3 rectangles : red, green, and blue. The red and Blue have `style="z-index : -1;"` while the green one has `style="z-index : 0;"`. We should see the green rectangle appearing on top of the others, no matter the ordrer of the `<rect>` elements. Here is the code :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100px" height="100px">
  <rect x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" style="fill : blue; z-index : -1;" />
  <rect x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" style="fill : green; z-index : 0;" />
  <rect x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" style="fill : red; z-index : -1;" /> 
</svg>
```

**PROBLEM**

The z-index property actually not works as my red `<rect>` is always on top of the others instead of the green being on top.

**QUESTION**

Can we safely say the `z-index` style property in SVG2 does not work yet, or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No UA supports all of SVG 2 and in fact there's no UA with z-index support currently.

According to [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kkqzcxY53h7liRYppLSSFG2sjaJ8V8TCP5rWLZK0AxA/edit?ts=584c8b81#gid=0) it's more likely that Firefox will support z-index than Chrome.

Comment: Is it still true in 2019?

Comment: @diraria I am afraid we still have the same issue right now. Use the JSFiddle I mentioned in my question as a "detector" if you need to regularily check whether it is supported or not.